# How to show message when there are no products related to search results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a search filter when there are no products related to search then it should display a message "No results found" I have tried the below code but it doesn't show the message

```
renderBrandDetails(brands){
    if(brands && brands.length > 0){
        const lowercasedFilter = this.state.filterData.toLowerCase();
        const filteredData = brands.filter(item => {
        return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
        item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
        );
     });
        return filteredData.map((brand) => {
            return(
                <div className="BrandData_Block">
                    <img src={brand.image} alt={brand.value} style={{ width: "80px", height: "80px" }}/>
                    <p>{brand.value}</p>   
                </div>
                )
            }) 
    }else {
        // return false
        return(
            <div>No results</div>
        )
    }
}
```

I have the below `render()` where there is an input field

```
 render() {
    const {filterData} = this.state
    return (
        <div className="BrandPageList_container">
            <div className="BrandPageList_SearchBrand">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search a brand name" className="BrandPageList_Input" value={filterData} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

I am using `renderBrandDetails` in the below function

```
getBrands = () => {
    if (this.isBrandsAvailable()) {
      return brandList.map((key) => {
        const brandsByCharacter = this.getBrandsByCharacter(key);
        if (brandsByCharacter?.length > 0) {
            let brandData = this.renderBrandDetails(brandsByCharacter)
            if(brandData.length ){
                return (
                    <div className="BrandWrapper_Container">
                      <div>{key}</div>
                      <div className="BrandWrapper_Grid">
                        {brandData}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
            }
        }
        return null;
      });
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };
```

How do I display the message? I have tried the below answer but the message is shown for other alphabets repeatedly as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9qZw.png)

Comment: Where are you use `renderBrandDetails`?

Comment: @Viet Can you check the updated question now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this. Here, instead of returning the map from `brandList.map(...)`, we store it in a variable called `brandContainers`. Then if that array is just filled with `null`, we return `<div>No results found</div>`, otherwise we return the array.

**Note:** Make sure to set `key` on each element in the array.

```
renderBrandDetails(brands) {
    if (brands && brands.length > 0) {
        const lowercasedFilter = this.state.filterData.toLowerCase();
        const filteredData = brands.filter(item => {
            return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
                item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
            );
        });
        return filteredData.map((brand) => {
            return (
                <div className="BrandData_Block" key={brand.value}>
                    <img src={brand.image} alt={brand.value} style={{ width: "80px", height: "80px" }}/>
                    <p>{brand.value}</p>   
                </div>
            )
        });
    } else {
        // return empty array
        return [];
    }
}

getBrands = () => {
    if (!this.isBrandsAvailable()) {
        return null;
    }
    
    const brandContainers = brandList.map((key) => {
        const brandsByCharacter = this.getBrandsByCharacter(key);
        
        if (!brandsByCharacter || brandsByCharacter.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        
        const brandData = this.renderBrandDetails(brandsByCharacter)
        
        if (brandData.length == 0)
            return null;
            
        return (
            <div className="BrandWrapper_Container" key={key}>
                <div>{key}</div>
                <div className="BrandWrapper_Grid">
                    {brandData}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });
    
    const filledContainers = brandContainers.filter(e => e !== null);
    
    return filledContainers.length > 0
        ? filledContainers
        : ( <div key="no-results">No results found.</div> );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Changes:

> - returning `[]` in else condition from `renderBrandDetails`
> - In `getBrands`, if `brandData.length` is 0 then displaying `no data found`

```
renderBrandDetails(brands){
    if(brands && brands.length > 0){
        const lowercasedFilter = this.state.filterData.toLowerCase();
        const filteredData = brands.filter(item => {
        return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
        item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
        );
     });
        return filteredData.map((brand) => {
            return(
                <div className="BrandData_Block">
                    <img src={brand.image} alt={brand.value} style={{ width: "80px", height: "80px" }}/>
                    <p>{brand.value}</p>   
                </div>
                )
            }) 
    }else {
        // return false
        return [];
    }
}

getBrands = () => {
    if (this.isBrandsAvailable()) {
      return brandList.map((key) => {
        const brandsByCharacter = this.getBrandsByCharacter(key);
        if (brandsByCharacter?.length > 0) {
            let brandData = this.renderBrandDetails(brandsByCharacter)
            if(brandData.length ){
                return (
                    <div className="BrandWrapper_Container">
                      <div>{key}</div>
                      <div className="BrandWrapper_Grid">
                        {brandData}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
            } else {
               return(
                  <div>No results</div>
               )
            }
        }
        return null;
      });
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };
```

Comment: I tried your code please check the image I have updated